# How to install Subversion JavaHL library with homebrew in 2021?

Tags: subclipse, javahl

I'm trying to use Subclipse on MacOS Big Sur with the JavaHL client.

I installed subversion via homebrew: `brew install subversion`

I tried to follow the [instructions on the Subclipse project page](https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki/JavaHL-on-OSX).

But I cannot find `libsvnjavahl-1.dylib` anywhere after the installation.

One [outdated blogpost](https://widerin.org/blog/svn-and-eclipse-in-osx/) instructs to use homebrew options, but the current homebrew formula for subversion does not support the mentioned options.

Update: Is this maybe because I am on Mac mini M1?

Answer (score 2):

I just used the instructions here:
https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki/JavaHL-on-OSX

Specifically:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/Extensions
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib
```

Worked just fine, YMMV.